# `make -n` starts a config.status

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I start a `make -n` of big project (multiple directories; Makefile and configure created with autotools); I think that nothing can be changed by this make; but it starts a `config.status --recheck` and regenerates some `Makefile`s and `config.h`.

Why does `make -n` starts anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the manual? If you look at [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Instead-of-Execution), you will see that recipe lines that start with a `+` and ones containing the `$(MAKE)` variable are always executed. Perhaps your Makefile contains such lines.

Comment: And no lines containing the variable `$(MAKE)` either?